# Tengo una lista enlazada

Tags: c

**Cómo le añado datos (10 enteros específicamente) y luego muestre por pantalla un informe de los elementos almacenados en la lista?**

Comment: por favor lee [ask] y de paso checa el [tour] pues aqui no se hacen tareas; deberás mostrar que llevas y que dudas específicas tienes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 void anadir_elemento() {
      struct _agenda *nuevo;

      /* reservamos memoria para el nuevo elemento */
      nuevo = (struct _agenda *) malloc (sizeof(struct _agenda));
      if (nuevo==NULL) printf( "No hay memoria disponible!\n");

      printf("\nNuevo elemento:\n");
      printf("Nombre: "); fflush(stdout);
      gets(nuevo->nombre);
      printf("Teléfono: "); fflush(stdout);
      gets(nuevo->telefono);

      /* el campo siguiente va a ser NULL por ser el último elemento
         de la lista */
      nuevo->siguiente = NULL;

      /* ahora metemos el nuevo elemento en la lista. lo situamos
         al final de la lista */
      /* comprobamos si la lista está vacía. si primero==NULL es que no
         hay ningún elemento en la lista. también vale ultimo==NULL */
      if (primero==NULL) {
         printf( "Primer elemento\n");
         primero = nuevo;
         ultimo = nuevo;
         }
      else {
           /* el que hasta ahora era el último tiene que apuntar al nuevo */
           ultimo->siguiente = nuevo;
           /* hacemos que el nuevo sea ahora el último */
           ultimo = nuevo;
      }
 }

 void mostrar_lista() {
      struct _agenda *auxiliar; /* lo usamos para recorrer la lista */
      int i;

      i=0;
      auxiliar = primero;
      printf("\nMostrando la lista completa:\n");
      while (auxiliar!=NULL) {
            printf( "Nombre: %s, Telefono: %s\n",
                    auxiliar->nombre,auxiliar->telefono);
            auxiliar = auxiliar->siguiente;
            i++;
      }
      if (i==0) printf( "\nLa lista está vacía!!\n" );
 }
```

Comment: 2 cosas, responder a preguntas que no muestran el mas mínimo intento no es bien visto, segundo lo que haces poner sólo código se considera de baja calidad

Comment: bueno ok ok MR.